# GWT forbid History.back() to exit current site

Tags: java, gwt

I'm wondering if there is a simple way in GWT to forbid `History.back()` (or `.forward()`) to lead to an external site, and define a fallback url if one of this happen.

For example :
Assuming that `mysite.com#token`, contains a component triggering a `History.back()`.
I am on `stackoverflow.com`, I paste `mysite.com#token` in my browser, then click on my component which move me back to stackoverflow, is it possible that click goes in `mysite.com` instead as a back exit my site?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use this approach

```
 Window.addWindowClosingHandler(new ClosingHandler() {
  public void onWindowClosing(ClosingEvent event) {
     event.setMessage("Do you want to leave this site");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, but it doesn't solve my problem as it seems that you can't redirect the user in a CloseHandler.